# Does Linux have both a user-mode and a system-mode stack for each process it runs?

Tags: linux, unix

This is my assignment question. Now I understand that the difference between the user mode and kernel mode (I think that is system mode).

But my question is: How the process works in Linux? Does the system have both user mode and system mode stacks for each process it runs?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that this question has already been answered here:

1. [What is the difference between kernel stack and user stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941992/what-is-the-difference-between-kernel-stack-and-user-stack)
2. [kernel stack and user space stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12911841/kernel-stack-and-user-space-stack)

That is, a userspace process has only one stack, a pointer to which is defined in the second element of the `task_struct` in `include/linux/sched.h` (about line 1045 in 3.12).

There is a possibility of some confusion with the per-thread kernel stack, as noted in the above posts. In a sense, a process can have one or more stacks, userspace and kernel space, depending on the number of threads it has at any point in time. The connection between the per-thread kernel stack, the thread and the process `task_struct` is described in this [lecture](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~junfeng/10sp-w4118/lectures/l07-proc-linux.pdf) by Junfeng Yang.